# Issue with string manipulation in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have an issue with string manipulation in c#. Please check the follwoing expression :

```
public static string UNID =  ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
.Claims.Single(c => c.ClaimType.Contains("nameidentifier")).Value.Substring( //issue is here
```

I want to point the value in the substring function for applying the indexOf function on it. I tried `this` keyword but not working :

```
public static string UNID =  ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
.Claims.Single(c => c.ClaimType.Contains("nameidentifier")).Value.Substring(this.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I know that we can do the same thing by breaking the expression into parts like :

```
var value = ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
.Claims.Single(c => c.ClaimType.Contains("nameidentifier")).Value;

var UNID = value.Substring(value.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

But if there is any solution for this just like i was trying with `this` keyword. Then please let me know ?

Comment: Isn't it more readable when you break it into parts?

Comment: If you really really want to do this in just one expression, you might try using a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static string UNID =  ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims
  .Where(c => c.ClaimType.Contains("nameidentifier"))
  .Select(c => c.Value.Substring(c.Value.IndexOf('/')+1))
  .Single();
```

- first select the requested claimtype
- then convert that to the correct value-substring
- and take the only (expected) value

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think having it as two separate lines is the best way to do this, but if you are dead set on one line you can use `Split` instead.  The second parameter indicates that you only want to split on the first delimiter.

```
var UNID = ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
    .Claims.Single(c => c.ClaimType.Contains("nameidentifier"))
    .Value.Split(new[] {'/'}, 2)[1];
```